# misunderstanding of variable arguments type

Tags: clojure

I am trying to solve a clojure problem where I implement my own comp function.

I have the following expression that works how I expect:

```
(reduce #(apply %2 [%1]) [1 2 3 4] [rest reverse])
```

This gives an output of

```
(4 3 2)
```

I have tried abstracting this into a function like this:

```
(((fn [& funcs]
        (fn [& args]
       (reduce #(apply %2 [%1]) args funcs)
      )) rest reverse) [1 2 3 4])
```

But I get the following error when I run it:

> CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.ArraySeq
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Number,
>   compiling:(/Users/paulcowan/projects/scratch/src/scratch/core.clj:1:1)

To me the only difference that I can see is how that funcs and args are different types than the vectors that I created in the first example.

Why does `reduce` and `apply` behave differently in the second example?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I wonder why you could get such an exception, your code is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't get any error messages (nor correct result):

```
user> (((fn [& funcs]
          (fn [& args]
            (reduce #(apply %2 [%1]) args funcs))) rest reverse) [1 2 3 4])
;; => ()
```

Difference between the two examples is that in the first one you pass value `[1 2 3 4]` into `reduce`, while in the second one you pass `[[1 2 3 4]]` (because `args` is meant to keep all arguments of the function as one vector.

This will work:

```
user> (((fn [& funcs]
          (fn [args]
            (reduce #(apply %2 [%1]) args funcs))) rest reverse) [1 2 3 4])
;; => (4 3 2)
```

However, to get a function for functional composition that will be able to take any number of arguments, you should write something like this:

```
user> (defn my-comp [& fncs]
        (fn [& args]
          (reduce #(%2 %1) ; you can omit apply here, as %2 is already function
                           ; and %1 is always one value, as noisesmith noticed
                  (apply (first fncs) args)
                  (rest fncs))))
;; => #'user/my-comp
user> (def my-fnc (my-comp rest reverse))
;; => #'user/my-fnc
user> (my-fnc [1 2 3 4])
;; => (4 3 2)
```

It will work fine, because only first function should have ability to take many arguments, as others will be applied to value returned by previously called function.

Comment: since a function can only return one result, you can take apply out of the reducing function, and just use `#(%2 %1)`

Comment: This `my-comp` is more clearly written `(defn my-comp [& fncs] (apply comp (reverse fncs)))`. It is just `comp` in the wrong order.

Comment: @A.Webb you just used `comp` to define `my-comp`. What's the point in that?

Comment: @A.Webb, Good catch, although it is not a problem here, in OP's original example it works the same way (functions get applied from left to right).

Comment: @A.Webb The whole point of OPs code was to define his own `comp` function (I guess without using comp, otherwise he could just do `(def my-comp comp)`). That's why I'm being picky here.

Comment: @soulcheck Ah, gotcha, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
(defn my-comp [& fns]
  (fn [x] (reduce #(%2 %1) x fns)))
```

giving

```
((my-comp rest reverse) [1 2 3 4])
;(4 3 2)
```

1. As it should, `my-comp` returns an `identity` function for an empty argument list.
2. But it expects all functions, including the first applied, 
   to take a single argument.

To get round (2), adapt it as follows:

```
(defn my-comp [& fns]
  (if (empty? fns)
    identity
    (let [[f & fs] fns]
      (fn [& args] (reduce #(%2 %1) (apply f args) fs)))))
```

Apart from (1), this merely rephrases [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25628876/1562315).

---

**For fun ...**

We could define `my-comp` in terms of [the standard `comp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/comp):

```
(defn my-comp [& fns] (apply comp (reverse fns)))
```

But it probably makes more sense the other way round, since `comp` has to reverse its argument list in general:

```
(defn comp [& fns] (apply my-comp (reverse fns)))
```

We could even define an argument reverser

```
(defn rev-args [f] (fn [& args] (apply f (reverse args))))
```

... which turns a function into one that does the same thing to a reversed argument list.

Then

```
(def comp (rev-args my-comp))
```

or vice-versa:

```
(def my-comp (rev-args comp))
```